# Difference between 2 dates not zero

Tags: php

I have 2 dates, set as `datetime1` and `datetime2`. I need to show the difference between them and here is the problem:
As of now I look for the difference the following way:

```
$interval = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
$data[] = floor($interval/(60*60*24)) . " days";
```

That shows me the difference, but if the two dates are the same it shows (logically) `0 days`.

How to display the difference, if I need to show it in the case of the same date as `1 day` instead of `0 days`. I need to display, that it took 1 day for the user to complete the programming course and it doesn't make sence to show 0.

Comment: So what if there's an interval of 1 day. What should it show then?

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php):

```
$data[] = max(1, floor($interval/(60*60*24))) . " day(s)";
```

This way, whatever the value, you'll display at least 1 day.

Comment: It woorked perfektly fine for me, Thanks X.L.Ant

Answer (score 0):

Moving the assignment into a variable and using the variable to control the value added to **$data** would work.

```
$interval = floor(($datetime2 - $datetime1)/86400);
$data[] = ($interval > 0) ? $interval.' days' : '1 day';
```

Answer (score -1):

just create a function with above code and store the difference result in variable if difference is zero the set the value 1 otherwise the difference value

```
 function myfunc()
{
$interval = $datetime2 - $datetime1;
$data = floor($interval/(60*60*24)) . " days";
if($data > 0) 
then return $data;
else
return 1;
}
```

Comment: I hate to say this, but this code won't work.  $datetime1 and $datetime2 would need to be parameters or identified with the global keyword.  This would yield a run time error.

Comment: @user2182349 that is just a psuedo code to make the logic clear